Deriving the log-likelihood function for ACD (Autoregressive Conditional Duration) models
I am trying to understand the procedure that is shown in this survey to obtain the log-likelihood function to estimate the parameters for an ACD model:
PACURAR, Maria. Autoregressive conditional duration models in finance: a survey of the theoretical and empirical literature. Journal of economic surveys, 2008, 22.4: 711-751.
In what follows, I am referring to page 714 of this survey.
Define $\psi_i \equiv E[x_i | \mathcal{F}_{i-1}]$ and the new variable $\epsilon_i \equiv \frac{x_i}{\psi_i}$, where we assume that $\epsilon_i$ is independent and identically distributed. It follows that $g(x_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}) = g(x_i | \psi_i)$. However, I do not understand how we get that $g(x_i | \mathcal{F}_{t-1}) = \psi_i^{-1} p(x_i/\psi_i)$, where $p(\epsilon)$ is the density of $\epsilon$ which has non-negative support. From that point I can then understand how we achieve the log-likelihood function.
